# Library search returns no results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a library with 4 documents in it.  Three of the documents has the word "template" in the name.  There is an additional multi-select choice column where template is an option.  Further, one of the documents has the word "template" in the text of the .docx.  Why would a library search return zero results for "template"?

Comment: Have you added this documents recently in library? Search crawl is completed? You tried searching with wild characters like `template*` or something?

Comment: Template is the last word, so it would have to be *template, but that didn't work.  I considered the crawl aspect and ran in incremental with no changes.  So I'm trying a full and will update if that changes the situation.

Comment: @Jammin4CO: keep in mind that searching `*template` is not supported. So: If you field is `foo-template` the word-breaker will recognize `template` as a single word, and serching for template should yield the result. However, if the name was `footemplate` searching for `template` probably would yield no results.

Comment: @Jammin4CO SharePoint doesn't work with prefixes in search keywords, that's the reason why ```*tempalte``` won't work. If those files have the same content SharePoint crawl will recognize them as the same file and will treat them as unique though they have different file names. Please, take care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could check crawl log and see if items were crawled, as shown below.

[image]
And search with other columns’ value, see whether there are results returned.

Start full crawl and search again.

Comment: This got me the needed information.  The users had turned on minor versions and only editors can see minors.  Therefore the "template" was not crawled.